# How can I find a variable in file by grep in Linux?

Tags: linux, string, variables, grep

I try to do grep on a variable but it does not work.

Given a file which contains the following strings:

```
*cccddd  
eeefff  
aaabbb*  
dddeee
```

I try to find a line which contains "aabb" as shown below, but it does not work.

```
set var = *"aabb"*  
*grep "$var" file.txt*
```

When I do the grep without putting the string into a variable as shown below, it works:

```
grep *aabb file.txt*
```

How could it work also with a variable?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Edit your question and add information about your used shell.

Comment: `set var = value` implies the `csh`. Please confirm that. ALSO the `*` characters are confusing. Do you mean shell wild-card chars or are you trying to make **bold** text in your question? Update your QUESTION. Don't reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: If you are using CSH then see https://www.google.com/search?q=CSH+why+not

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
f="aabb"
awk -v var=$f '$0~var' file
aaabbb*
```

This test if line does contain the the content of variable `f` and if found print the line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in bash shell, and there this is very easy:

```
Linux prompt> var="aabb"
Linux prompt> grep $var file.txt
aaabbb*
```

Why are you trying to work with `set var=...`?